buying tbills from https://www.treasurydirect.gov/log-in/
I am planning to buy tbills from treasurydirect . This page says that auction happens every week then why is there so much of lag between my transaction date 05-18-2024 and Issue Date:  06-04-2024?

below is my first attempt


Transaction:
Date: 05-18-2024
Description:  Purchase Requested
Par Amount:   $100.00
Confirm #:    IAAAA
Confirm #:    IAAAA
Type: 17-Week Bill
Par Amount:   $100.00
Number of Reinvestments:  0

Issue Date:   06-04-2024



Can i sell these tbills say after 4 weeks through the same site?


I just checked the website and the 17 week instrument is auctioned every week.
When you use the treasury direct website, you not only specify the length of the investment you are buying, you also get to pick the specific auction date from the list of future auctions.
I used this feature recently because I was going to be on vacation  when the next auction was taking place. I placed my order before leaving for my vacation, even though it was the auction after next I wanted to invest money in.
I always have to check that I am picking the correct week when I am staring a new purchase instead of rolling over my investment.
I have never sold a tbill early. A comment from D Stenley included a link to this page: Selling Treasury Bills:

Selling Treasury Bills
You can hold Treasury bills until they mature or sell them before they
mature.
To sell a bill you hold in TreasuryDirect or Legacy TreasuryDirect,
first transfer the bill to a bank, broker, or dealer, then ask the
bank, broker, or dealer to sell the bill for you.
How you transfer a bill to a bank, broker, or dealer depends on
whether you hold the bill in TreasuryDirect or Legacy TreasuryDirect.
For a bill held in TreasuryDirect:

Go to "Manage Direct"
Choose "Transfer securities"
Identify the bill or bills you want to transfer
Choose "External Transfer"
Click the link for FS Form 5511,"TreasuryDirect Transfer Request"
Complete FS Form 5511 and mail it as directed on the form

For a bill held in Legacy TreasuryDirect, complete "Security Transfer Request" (FS Form 5179) and mail it as directed on the form.


could you reply the 2nd question?

I believe the second question is answered: you must work with a bank, broker, or dealer to sell it before maturity!; you can't do it through the Treasury department's website.
